# Web Scraping in php? need a specific piece of data

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull a piece of data from the website www.coinmarketcap.com
specifically, the market cap  number up the top.

I've been trying to figure this out the past hour or so and have read MANY different ways people use these web scrapers but have not been successful at all. Could someone shed some light?

Comment: if you need something that is displayed on their (home)page you can use DOM as well .. check out the source code and write something simple to get what you want..

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways, but the easiest is just take their url:
https://files.coinmarketcap.com/generated/stats/global.json

Please note: They might not like this. Maybe they dont want external parties to use their scripts. So also buidl a check wether the file still exists and doesnt give a 403 back.

**How did I find this:**

- When the page loads,the header with the information loads *after* the document ready, so it can not have been made by the server and has to be AJAX.
- Now we know that it is AJAX, we want to know which file. You do this by opening your browsers console. All browsers have a network tab, showing all resources being loaded. When you filter by XHR you see all AJAX request. Then you try to find the right one.